# For cycle causes unwanted "exit sub" event

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

really weird behavior in Vb.net 2010 Express. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim a As Integer
        '... Other lines...'
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(App_Path & "midi\")
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        For a = 0 To diar1.Count
            midrep(a) = diar1(a).Name
        Next a
        Preload()
End Sub
```

For some reason, the last line with "Preload()" instruction is not executed. (I checked with a breakpoint, it never even gets to it).

If I remove the cycle, it works fine. With the cycle, I get no errors or warnings, but the last line is completely ignored. The for cycle is properly executed.

I need the cycle before Preload().

Anyone knows how to solve the issue?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Could you show all code relating to midrep, including the definition and everything that changes its value?

Comment: Also, this is just a guess, but are you using other appdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're not getting out of the `For` loop because you're exceeding the bounds of either `midrep` (which you haven't given us the type of) or `diar1`, which is clearly an array of `FileInfo` objects.

In fact, regardless of `midrep`'s definition, you're definitely exceeding the bounds of `diar1`, as `diar1.Count` is always going to be one higher than the last available index. You need to stop looping **before** you get to `diar1.Count`.

```
For a = 0 To diar1.Count - 1
'                       ^^^^
    midrep(a) = diar1(a).Name
Next a
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! Good catch!
I'm a little surprised that I got no error message... I had no idea that array bound check could be disabled in VB.NET and no idea at all that the default setting was disabled! I'll see if I can enable it for this project (I have no performance problems, it is a very simple app) Thanks again!

Comment: BTW: I just tried again: no luck, it still exits the sub. :-(